# Boost Scoped Ptr - Declaration vs Allocation

Tags: c++, boost, scoped-ptr

The below code is working fine:

```
scoped_ptr<clsA> pclObjA(new clsA());
```

But the below statements are not working:

```
scoped_ptr<clsA> pclObjA;

// some statements

pclObjA(new clsA());
```

I am getting compilation error like below:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(boost::scoped_ptr<clsA>) (clsA*)’
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Additional Info: the `clsA` derived from `claX`

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
pclObjA(new clsA());
```

does not invoke the constructor (and the `scoped_ptr<>` instance already exists anyway), but  is attempting to invoke a function call operator with signature `scoped_ptr<clsA>::operator()(clsaA*)` which does not exist.

Use [`boost::scoped_ptr<T>::reset(T*)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm#reset) to assign a dynamically allocated object after construction:

```
pclObjA.reset(new clsA());
```